# Forward jboss http request to cpp

Tags: c++, jboss

I have a server with jboss that run war with the following url http:external_ip:8080/myweb

In the same server i also have a cpp process. 
I want this processes to also be an http server.
But i can't open another port for http in the same server (customer limitation). I need to use the same port for jboss and my cpp process.

So i want my cpp process to receive request that arrive on http:external_ip:8080/REST
Is there a built in feature in jboss to forward all these request to 127.0.0.1:3000 ?

I have found something in jboss7 call rewrite
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/rewrite.html

 Although i am using jboss 6 till now. Is this what i am searching for?
Is there a something similar in jboss6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such feature in jboss as a mod_proxy like apache
One way to solve your problem would be to write your own servlet that redirects calls from a context root to a backend service.
Or 
use this 
https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet
which seams to be what you are looking for.